# Jar hell - force load one version

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, jar

Is there a way to force a java application to load a particular version of a jar, and not include the other version in the classpath?

Many other users here have noted that Elasticsearch unit tests throw jar hell errors. I have tried all the suggestions, and nothing has worked. I have set up tons and tons of 'exclusions' in my pom.xml, and this has not helped. How exactly is this jar being loaded?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: found jar hell in test classpath
..
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!
class: javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter
jar1: /Users/xx/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/servlet/jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
jar2: /Users/xx/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/servlet/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
```

How to find which jar is linked to jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar? I have tried using tattletale(this did not generate reports) and maven-duplicate-finder(this did not find anything). I could hack it to set the jar-check option to false, but then I get shadowing errors.

These jars do not show up in my maven dependency tree.
I tried deleting the two versions from my .m2 directory, but they just popup again when I am running the app - is there a way to find out where it is being loaded from?

Comment: I usually use `mvn dependency:tree` for this purpose

Comment: I have done that.

Comment: Try deleting (or moving out of the way) the `/Users/xx/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/servlet` directory and see if you can detect what is downloading them during a build.

Comment: Try `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true` This will show you any shadowed dependency.

Comment: I tried verbose for the maven dependancy tree, and only one version is being loaded. I tried deleting them from my .m2 directory, but they just popup again when I am running the app - is there a way to find out where it is being loaded from? Will update my item above too